# I want change the item description in another div ( bootstrap carousel)

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-hooks, bootstrap-5

I rendered all the imagine using the map method, what i want to do i want to keep track of the current image index so i can change the item description which is located in another div, or you can provide me another solution.

App.js :

```
import Carousel from 'react-bootstrap/Carousel';
import './style.css'
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';
import Row from 'react-bootstrap/Row';
import Col from 'react-bootstrap/Col';
import { useState } from 'react';

function App(props) {
 
  return (
    <Container>
      <Row>
        <Col>
        <Carousel className='mycarousel'>
      {
        props.adem.map((element)=>(
         <Carousel.Item key={element.id} id={element.id}>
      <img
        className="myImage"
        src={element.images.url[0]}
        alt="First slide"
      />
      
      
         </Carousel.Item>
     ))
    }
    </Carousel>
        </Col>

        <Col>
        
        </Col>
      </Row>
      </Container>
    

       
    
  
  
  );
}


export default App;
```

As you can see the map method render the images but i wanna display the item description in an individual col , not inside the slide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the `activeIndex` attribute for the Carousel element to conditionally render the description?

You could get the index of the currently visible card by reading the `activeIndex` attribute and then check if the activeIndex === card index and render the corresponding description.

Hope this helps